# Is there any CLI/API tool for RVC conversion [not GUI]?

Tags: audio, command-line-interface, data-science, audio-streaming, data-conversion

So the task is to take `input.wav` and infer it to `output.wav` with my `model.pth` and `model.index` using [RVC](https://github.com/RVC-Project/Retrieval-based-Voice-Conversion-WebUI).

I do not find any solutions for CLI or API [RVC](https://github.com/RVC-Project/Retrieval-based-Voice-Conversion-WebUI) conversion, there are only GUI approaches.

Answer (score 1):

Yes with inferance python scripts in Tool `infer.py`.

Or you can simply reduce processor threats and wait 1 hour and yours is finaly trained !

For `infer.py` see these github thread `Q7`

https://github.com/RVC-Project/Retrieval-based-Voice-Conversion-WebUI/wiki/FAQ-(Frequently-Asked-Questions)#q7how-to-train-and-infer-without-the-webui